# how do oscillations build up initially although the circuit has no external applied input?

Tags: amplifier, oscillator

In practical we got some king of oscillation even before given input power. We   have built wien bridge oscillator like this one.

[image].

image from [electronicdesign.com](http://electronicdesign.com/passives/analysis-digitally-controlled-wien-bridge-oscillator)

Comment: How do you get oscillation without power?

Comment: Show a schematic of what you have made.  Do you mean power to the circuit, or just a voltage at an input?

Comment: In general, oscillators start up by amplifying the inevitable noise that exists in any circuit.

Comment: I'd point out that the one shown is just a "random" schematic out of Google images, it'd be good to see the actual design.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot of Q in the RC Wien bridge oscillator circuit you show. I suggest perhaps some pickup from external noise sources.

As Dave Tweed said, oscillators start by amplifying noise that happens to be close to the frequency they are tuned to. For that reason, very high Q oscillators may have trouble starting. Wien bridge oscillators tend to have gain that is deliberately marginal because you want to minimize distortion in the sinusoidal output (and minimize the range and responsiveness of the AGC circuitry).

Try disconnecting your circuit entirely and see if you can still see the "oscillation".